# How to visualize grouped clusters in a graph

Tags: visualization

I was trying to use Gephi, which seems to have a 'group' feature in some of the WIKI explanations, but actually does not appear in my GUI. There is a tool that creates groups from partitions, but it ignores the node attributes when creating those groups, and importantly removes the actual name of the partition and picks some random node or edge name instead.

I also tried collapsing the graph in networkx using `quotient_graph`and making the partitions manually based on the node attribute. However this also removed the attributes and made subgraphs instead of just reducing it.

Then I tried cytoscape, which had the autoannotation plugin. It was pretty close, although did some weird name changes as it wouldnt just let me select the node attribute name to make the groups. However after I was able to collapse the nodes, I am not able to use the layouts well.

Is there a simple approach to this, or something I am missing in the ways that I tried?